# Apache 2: log only 400 errors and not other 4XX

Tags: apache, logging, http-headers, http-status-code-400, http-error

In Apache2.4 I would need to log as much as I can for requests resulting in a 400 error.
Is it possible to achieve this without setting the logging level to `debug`? Is is also possible to log only 400 errors and not any other 4XX?

Thanks!

Setting the logging level to `debug` might work but it would log way too many errors (404, 403 ...) and i don't need that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

change `/tmp/400errors.log` to where you want to log to output to

## Method 1 - SetEnvIf

use `SetEnvIf` in apache

add this to `httpd.conf`

```
# Set an environment variable for 400 series errors
SetEnvIfNoCase Response_Status "^400" LOG_400_ERRORS

# Define a custom log format that includes the error status
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined_with_status

# Use conditional logging based on the environment variable
CustomLog /tmp/400errors.log combined_with_status env=LOG_400_ERRORS
```

## Method 2 - Mod Rewrite

use `mod_rewrite` in apache, either in your site config, or htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect 400 series errors to a custom error log
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_STATUS} ^400
RewriteRule ^ - [E=LOG_400_ERRORS]

# Define a custom log format that includes the error status
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined_with_status

# Use conditional logging based on the environment variable
CustomLog /tmp/400errors.log combined_with_status env=LOG_400_ERRORS
```